# What is the recommended way to save a nested dictionary/list where the inner most values are NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to save a nested dictionary where the innermost values are NumPy arrays.

I can directly use `np.savez` to save it (by unfolding the outermost key-value pairs). However, when I try to load this `.npz` file, I have to set `allow_pickle=True` to load the data properly. I noticed using `allow_pickle=True` is not safe, so I wonder what would be the recommended way to save and load a nested dictionary without using `allow_pickle=True`?

Comment: `pickle` is the most general tool for saving python objects, including `dict` and `list`.  `np.save` writes a numpy array.  For numeric array it is a close to being an exact copy of the array (as stored in memory).  If given something else it first "wraps" it in a numpy array (object dtype).  Same if the arrays are object dtype.  And it has to allow-pickle to do that (and load it back).  `savez`, if given a `dict` saves each value as `save` type `npy` file.  Anyways, for anything but a numeric dtype array, you have to use or allow `pickle`.

Comment: As long as you have control over the files - saving, and copying from one directory or machine to another - the "security" of pickle shouldn't be a big issue.